# Angular 2 hooks ngOnInit

Tags: typescript, angular

Which function called After `ngOnInit()` in angular 2? I want to called function after `ngOnInit()` is done. I am new to Angular 2. Kindly help me which is best thing to do in this case.

Comment: Are by any chance looking for `ngAfterViewInit()`? (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hook-sequence)

Comment: yes but not working in my case

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE; which life cycle hook you can use, it depends upon your usecase**.

## ngAfterContentInit

There is a life cycle of the component. you should check it here -  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

OR

If you want to call any **custom function** you can call it at the end of the `ngOnInit` function like below,

```
ngOnInit(){
  ...
  this.fun();
}

fun()
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your question is: `ngDoCheck(), This lifecycle hook Called immediately after **ngOnChanges** and **ngOnInit**.

check this official guide of angular 2 [Lifecycle Hooks.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) for more deep details.